# Bash command to determine which string in a group of strings is a prefix of another string

Tags: bash

Here's what I'm trying to do:
I have a folder for code repositories, and I'm looking for a bash command that can tell the "code root directory" of the current working directory. For example, if I'm currently in `~/repositories/my_program/folder1/folder2/`, I want the command to return `~/repositories/my_program/`.

I can get the working directory path with `pwd` and a list of projects using `ls ~/repositories/`. How do I determine which one of the `~/repositories/<match>` strings is a prefix of `pwd`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the directory right under `~/repositories`, you could do something like

```
$ sed -r "s#($HOME/repositories/[^/]*).*#\1#" <<<$PWD
/home/terdon/repositories/my_program
```

And to print `my_program` only:

```
$ sed -r "s#$HOME/repositories/([^/]*).*#\1#" <<<$PWD
my_program
```

To use `~/` instead, try

```
$ sed -r "s#$HOME(/repositories/[^/]*).*#~\1#" <<<$PWD
~/repositories/my_program
```

The idea is to match `$HOME/repositories/`, then one more directory (defined as the longest string of non-`/` characters: `[^/]*`).

Comment: Bash provides us with "Parameter Expansion" for manipulating strings. There is no need to fork() and use an external program like sed. Parameter Expansion expands parameters: "$foo", "$1". You can use it to perform string or array operations: "${file%.mp3}", "${0##*/}", "${files[@]: -4}". They should *always* be quoted. See: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073 and "Parameter Expansion" in man bash. Also see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe.

Comment: @RanyAlbegWein all true but getting `~/repositories/my_program` from `/home/terdon/repositories/my_program/folder1/folder2` requires something like `f="${PWD#/home/terdon/repositories/}"; echo "~/repositories/${f%%/*}"` which is 1) harder to understand, 2) more complex (requires two steps) 3) longer to type. While it will be marginally faster than the `sed` approach, which would be important in a larger script, I don't think this is worth it given the simplicity of the task at hand. Do feel free to post an answer with a pure shell solution though, it would be a useful addition.

Comment: I partially agree. The sed command provided in the solution isn't much more intuitive. Yes, for a on-the-fly solution, there is no need to be fast in this specific case. I have nothing to add more than the links I posted in my comment so i'll leave my answer as a comment, but I'll take your suggestion into account in the second chance.